# jaxb unmarshal xml element to object with some fields

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have some classes:

```
class Location  {   

    private Long id;   

    private String roomTitle;  

    protected Specialization specialization;
}

public class Specialization  {

    private Long id;

    private boolean archived;

    private String title;
}
```

and xml:

```html
<location id="10"> 
  <roomTitle>string</roomTitle>
  <specializationId>10</specializationId>
</location>
```

Can I unmarshal `specializationId` to `Location.specialization.id` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jaxb but SimpleXml can do it.

First we'll need to add some annotations:

```
public class Location  {
    private Long id;
    private String roomTitle;
    @XmlName("specializationId")
    protected Specialization specialization;
}

public class Specialization  {
    @XmlTextNode
    private Long id;
    private Boolean archived;
    private String title;
}
```

Note that `archived` is now a Boolean class. The regular boolean cannot be null. Next we serialize the xml to the Location class.

```
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Location l = simple.fromXml(xml, Location.class);
```

And then we can print the value

```
System.out.println(l.specialization.id);
```

This will print

```
10
```

SimpleXml is in maven central

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```